# Print second level menu in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

Drupal 8 markup changed quite a lot from Drupal 7 using the Twig Engine. We are developing a site with it. We want to print the second level menu links in there.

```
  {% if main_menu %}
  <nav id ="main-menu" class="navigation" role="navigation">
      {{ main_menu }}
  </nav> <!-- /#main-menu -->
```

This is how we print the menu in Drupal 8. A syntax im not quite used to.

How can i print. Second level links on the menu. Or the Menu Tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8), you should have access to `secondary_menu` as well, so:

```
{% if secondary_menu %}
  <nav id ="secondary-menu" class="navigation" role="navigation">
      {{ secondary_menu }}
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```

Generally speaking, you can use a [preprocess hook](https://drupal.org/node/1920746) to add variables. In this case that would be something like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['foo'] = 'bar'; // foo is available in the page template file
}
```

Comment: I will try this again and test if it works for my case. Thanks for the answer. I can't mark it as an answer right now. Before testing it.

Thanks again.

Comment: Worked as designed. I will try to print it on hover rather than onClick but the secondary menu is displayed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which theme you use, it may be that it is not a problem with the menu template. In my case, the (main) menu was configured to show only one level in the block settings.

I found out by chance, here is how to change it:

1. Go to https://<yourdrupalpage>/admin/structure/block
2. on the respective menu block item (e.g. main menu) click *configure*
3. adjust the number of visible menu levels to your needs

that should to the trick

Answer (score 1):

I did what Stephan Richter suggest but I forgot to check "Always display open" equivalent option in the menu item level1

So If you want your level 2 to be displayed, do not forget this option in the parent.